# Filling form fields of a webpage opened in a web view with React Native

Tags: react-native, webview

I'm working on a project that includes a module that helps with electricity recharge, so what happens is that the user's data is already saved in the app and when they choose to recharge, the app opens up [this](https://currencypin.com/PrepaidMeterPaymentsV2.0/cartwiz?c=IN&p=5&pm=tm) webpage in a web view.

Currently, I'm using WebBridgeView for opening the webpage as:-

```
render() {
    return (
        <WebViewBridge
            ref="webviewbridge"
            onBridgeMessage={this.onBridgeMessage.bind(this)}
            source={{uri: "https://currencypin.com/PrepaidMeterPaymentsV2.0/cartwiz?c=IN&p=5&pm=tm"}}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, what I want is that when the webpage opens, the **form fields come prefilled with the custom data that I have**. So that the only field that the user needs to fill on the page is the CAPTCHA.

I was following [this article](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/25/send-receive-data-between-react-native-and-webview.html) for achieving the same, but it actually assumes that the website is customizable. Which is not possible in my case because it belongs to a 3rd party vendor.

What are the ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `injectedJavaScript` prop from `WebView`.

First declare a `jsCode` variable:

```
const amount = 2
const jscode = `
  if (document.getElementById('txtAmount') == null) {
      // field not existing, deal with the error
    } else {
      document.getElementById('txtAmount').value = '${amount}';
    }
`
```

Please notice the " ` " character. Used to put variables in strings.

Then use it like so:

```
<WebViewBridge
  ref="webviewbridge"
  onBridgeMessage={this.onBridgeMessage.bind(this)}
  injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm after I added the prop `javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}` and encapsulated the WebView inside a root View container. Thank you so much for showing the proper way :)

Comment: Glad I could help, feel free to mark your post as solved.